# Resolving references of 2 or more different versions of the same assembly

Tags: .net, dependencies, version, .net-assembly

I understand this question was asked tens of times at least and there are a bunch of variations of the answer however nobody bothered to explain all the details and cover all the aspects of one or another approach. I’m talking about the famous warning looking like this

> No way to resolve conflict between "Deep, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f694e838567cfe72" and "Deep, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f694e838567cfe72". Choosing "Deep, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f694e838567cfe72" arbitrarily.
>   Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Deep, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f694e838567cfe72" from Version "1.0.0.0" [D:\Misc\Drive\Main\trunk\Application\DependencyResearch\Bin\Middle1\Deep.dll] to Version "2.0.0.0" [D:\Misc\Drive\Main\trunk\Application\DependencyResearch\Bin\Middle2\Deep.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.

The first and most popular answer you find is just add this to your app.config

```
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Deep" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="f694e838567cfe72" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
```

By adding this the warning is gone and the idea is quite clear. You instruct the framework to use version 2.0.0.0 of Deep assembly in all cases and that might work but usually it is not mentioned or simply assumed that it might work in very limited number of cases. Only if ALL code originally referencing version 1.0.0.0 calls only those methods which signature is not changed in version 2.0.0.0 and which internal functionality does not change a bit; otherwise you’ll face an unpredictable application behavior where an error or exception might happen in any part which worked before.

There is next popular answer just add this to your app.config

```
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Deep" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="f694e838567cfe72" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="Deep1\Deep.dll" />
        <codeBase version="2.0.0.0" href="Deep.dll" />
     </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
```

Adding this however does not remove the warning I started my question with. Besides that this approach is much better in regards to reliability and stability of the application. All code which used version 1.0.0.0 continues using that version and all code which used version 2.0.0.0 continues using that version. What I really don’t like about this solution is that the warning message is still displayed in every build. Does it mean that the conflict is not completely resolved? Why? Or is it just the compiler which does not understand that the conflict actually resolved? Having warnings in my build makes me worry.

GAC was mentioned a number of times but this is really not an option. There are more problems with GAC itself than it can solve.

With all above said it is quite obvious that the only right solution is to reference all versions of the same assembly to ensure stability of all parts of the code. If this is true is there a simple solution? Is there a way to tell compiler always add all referenced assemblies to the target binary folder placing conflicting assemblies into different folders using the version numbers as names or renaming assemblies adding version numbers to the names?

Is there a good article explaining in details this problem, all possible solutions, their advantages and disadvantages?